# What is the difference between Constraints and Annotations?

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, constraints

I've been studying Java EE 6 and I am confused about the difference between Annotations and Constraints. What exactly is the difference between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Annotations](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html) such as `@Deprecated`, `@WebServlet`, `@NotNull`, etcetera carry **metadata** with the class. Before annotations exist, this was usually done by XML configuration files. Annotations can be determined with help of Java Reflection.

[Constraints](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html) are business rules which are to be applied on classes and/or fields (properties) of the class. For example, if the business rule mandates that the user name may never be null, then you'd like to put the `@NotNull` annotation to define the constraint.

```
public class User {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    // ...
}
```

I see in your question history that you're familiar with JSF, the Java EE supplied web MVC framework. JSF can make use of it to validate the user input.

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{user.name}" />
<h:message for="username" />
```

When the user leaves the input field blank, a message will be displayed which informs the user that the value may not be null (the exact message itself is customizable).

#### See also:

- [JSF 2.0 tutorial - Finetuning validation](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html#FinetuningValidation)